# Oracle - Audit Trail for a specific user

Tags: oracle, security, oracle11g, audit, audit-trail

As stated on the topic , I am looking for a way for us to track on the activities of the specific user. May or may not have the SYSDBA or SYSOPER privilege.

For example , HR.

I would like to know what are the details of his login , what are the objects that are changed by him , what were their original values , SQL statements executed , what procedure/functions that were executed etc.

Could we set up such audit trail log in Oracle 11gR2 Standard/Enterprise?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you need to enable auditing in your database by setting `audit_trail` parameter as shown below-

```
SQL> alter system set audit_trail='OS|DB|DB,EXTENDED|XML|XML, EXTENDED';
```

[Initialization Parameters Used for Auditing](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10575/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50514)

Then, you can audit user as-

```
SQL>CONNECT sys/password AS SYSDBA

SQL> AUDIT ALL BY username BY ACCESS;
SQL> AUDIT SELECT TABLE, UPDATE TABLE, INSERT TABLE, DELETE TABLE BY username BY ACCESS;
SQL> AUDIT EXECUTE PROCEDURE BY username BY ACCESS;
```

[AUDIT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_4007.htm#SQLRF01107)

Audit records can be found in `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL` view.Following query list all audit related views.

```
SQL>SELECT view_name FROM dba_views WHERE view_name LIKE 'DBA%AUDIT%';
```

Fine-grained auditing is available in Enterprise Edition only.

[Feature Availability by Edition](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e47877/editions.htm#DBLIC116)