# View users activities history in Oracle Database 12c

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I have created some individual users in Oracle Database 12c, so the users can work their specific activities.
I have to monitor and report the queries/history of each users.
Is there a way so I can generate or view activity logs of each user?

I am having SYS user account in Oracle database 12c, and created usres like ABC and XYZ .. needs to provide activity logs of both users.

Please share if there specific way or script to find out by daily basis, weekly or all time history.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle - Audit Trail for a specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976094/oracle-audit-trail-for-a-specific-user)

Comment: What sort of activities are you talking about? If you mean database actions Oracle has built-in capabilities for broad and fine-grained auditing. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/auditing.htm#DBSEG1023). If you mean application tasks then that's something you'll need to build for yourself.

Comment: Database actions activities like view , update , drop etc sql execution history by each user

Comment: I think you can use a solution for DAM like DataSunrise(www.datasunrise.com) or Imperva. These solutions don't free.