# How can I audit all DDL for a specific schema in Oracle with the Unified Audit Trail?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c, audit-trail

I'm running Oracle 19C and looking for a way to audit all DDL for a given schema. Specifically, I want to be able to audit all changes to the schema itself. Things like creating, dropping, and altering tables and views, modifying and/or compiling functions and packages, and even truncate. I'm not interested in any DML such as inserts, updates, or selects. I know I can do something like:

```
CREATE AUDIT POLICY ALTER_TABLE_POLICY
ACTIONS ALTER ON MYSCHEMA.TABLE1,
ACTIONS ALTER ON MYSCHEMA.TABLE2,
ACTIONS ALTER ON MYSCHEMA.TABLE3;
 
AUDIT POLICY ALTER_TABLE_POLICY;
```

But this seems very tedious for what I want to do. Not to mention, it doesn't account for creating new tables. Surely there is a better way to get all the changes I want.

I did see this topic here: [Oracle - Audit Trail for a specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976094/oracle-audit-trail-for-a-specific-user)

But that seems to be more for following all the actions of a specific user. I want to track the actions ON a specific user/schema. Not to mention, a lot of the results I see when I look for this seem to focus more on solutions prior to 12c and above.

How can I audit the DDL for a given schema utilizing the unified audit trail?

Answer (score 1):

There is `enable_ddl_logging`, but it has some problems:

1. It only gives you the SQL, not identifying information.
2. It can fill up an alert log if you have application processes that do a lot of truncates and temp table work.
3. The alert log is not (easily) programmatically accessible.
4. Only the DBAs can look at it.
5. It's all-or-nothing. The whole DB, every DDL.

A better alternative is to create a system trigger (`CREATE TRIGGER myschema.tr_audit_ddl AFTER DDL ON SCHEMA`) and populate your own custom audit table. Within this trigger you have predefined variables available:

```
           ora_sysevent
           ora_dict_obj_owner
           ora_dict_obj_name
           ora_dict_obj_type
           original_sql_txt
           ora_revokee
           ora_grantee
```

You could pull in additional fields from `SYS_CONTEXT/USERENV` and `v$session` of course. You can decide what DDLs to ignore because they're too frequent. You can control who can access this information, how long you keep it, etc... you can even use table-drive rules. This is much more powerful than other options.

Just be sure, as with any system trigger, that you trap all exceptions (`WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL`) in the outermost block to avoid disrupting an application process if you have a problem in your trigger code. It's also wise to break the dependency chain to your logging table and any other objects you reference by using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` so you can trap missing object references or other parse problems at run time rather than have an invalid trigger that prevents application DDL from succeeding.